# How to remove vertical gaps in constarint layout

Tags: android

I am using constarintLayout. The intention is to present five ui components aligned vertically with no gap separating them. In xml file, the five ui component are separated with a large gap separating them.
how can I reduce or eliminate the gap.

I referred to some examples in the internet, but it was not clear how to remove the separating gaps

**code**:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_start_gps_reading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/str_start_gps_readings"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ll_lat_container"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_lat_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_start_gps_reading"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_long_container">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lat_readings"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_lat_readings_value"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_long_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_lat_container"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ll_alt_container">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/long_readings"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_long_readings_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_alt_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_long_container"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ll_acc_container">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/alt_readings"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_alt_readings_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_acc_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_alt_container"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/acc_readings"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_acc_readings_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the bottom constraint of the last linearlayout the gaps go away

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_acc_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll_alt_container">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/acc_readings"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_acc_readings_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: would you please explain why removing the last ui component could solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are evenly spaced out that means you successfully created a vertical chain.

Default chain mode is `spread` and this is what you're experiencing. What you actually want is to change your chain mode to `packed` which will remove all gaps.

You accomplish it by modifying first item in the chain (for vertical chains that means top-most):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_start_gps_reading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/str_start_gps_readings"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ll_lat_container"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"/>
```

`layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle` changes chain style.

`layout_constraintVertical_bias` positions your packed views relative to parent: `0.0` is on top, `1.0` on the bottom and `0.5` is centered (default).

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain) for more details.